# How to save image jpg or other format after uploading as png using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp:FileUpload and I want to save all uploaded images of all acceptable formats as png images in the Images forlder on website, my upload code is:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fup2.HasFile)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?i).*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|tif)$");
            string uFile = fup2.FileName;
            if (reg.IsMatch(uFile))
            {
                string saveDir = Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/");
                string SavePath = saveDir + uFile;
                fup2.SaveAs(SavePath);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Error");
            }

        }
    }
```

I also tried using

`var tempImg = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/"));
tempImg.Save("a.tiff", ImageFormat.png);`

It keeps throwing `file not found exception`

Any new ideas?

Comment: That code should work .... I'm not sure about your regex  ... what error you are getting?

Comment: It is working for uploading images and saving it to Images folder, but how to convert the image to `png` before saving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Bitmap.FromStream`. Something like:

```
 using System.Drawing;

 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (fup2.HasFile)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?i).*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|tif)$");
        string uFile = fup2.FileName;
        if (reg.IsMatch(uFile))
        {
            string saveDir = Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/");
            string SavePath = saveDir + Path.GetFileName(uFile) + ".png";
            Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(fup2.PostedFile.InputStream);
            b.Save(SavePath, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Error");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, altered `fup2.PostedFile.InputStream` in your suggested code and it worked quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `Image.FromFile` -> `Save` should do the trick, but i don't see how you are using the correct path - you just point at the directory and not the actual file when calling `FromFile`

As a side note, doing this processing on a web processing thread is not a great idea but for small load it could work.